# Azure Service Bus long running queue

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I am new to this and maybe i got the entire concept wrong, i wanted to have a permanently running background job in a container, which continously receives messages from an Azure Service Bus. There are going to be times when there will be no messages for more than an hour and there are going to be times when messages will come in flooding.

I have set my bus up in Node.JS like below.

Now when there are no messages for a certain amount of time the is going to resolve to an empty array as indicated by idleTimeoutInSeconds.
Is the Azure Service Bus intended to be used to like i anticipated?
If not is there something more fitting i can use to solve that?

I would need something that runs permanently and reacts to new messages send.

EDIT: A web server wouldnt necessary work in some scenarios, even though it would be a good fit.

```
async function main(){
  const sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString); 
  const queueClient = sbClient.createQueueClient(queueName);
  const receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
  try {
    while(true){
        const messages = await receiver..receiveMessages(10);
        console.log("Received messages:");
        console.log(messages.map(message => message.body));
        }
        } finally {
        await sbClient.close();
        }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

Comment: Azure Functions comes to mind as it's specifically tailored for scenarios where messages flow is variable. Also, you don't have to worry about scale.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have shared seems to be using version 1 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

While your code snippet might serve the purpose, you can leverage the `subscribe` method that is offered in version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK which is specifically designed for the use-case you have mentioned(receiving forever).

[Equivalent to the `registerMessageHandler` API in version 1]

You can refer to the [receiveMessagesStreaming.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/receiveMessagesStreaming.ts) sample code that uses version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) can run continuously and subscribe to a Service Bus Queue/Topic.

I'm quite certain that even after an hour of inactivity it will still respond to new messages after that.

I've only implemented it in C# though, not nodejs although I'm sure the practice is the same.